# install4j: Autoupdate from a local file location?

Tags: install4j

I.e. the idea is to use a URL like `file:///path/to/download/location/update.xml`.
Are there any gotchas if we go that route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do that, HTTP is not a requirement.